# Box API get access_token through python

Tags: python, api, access-token, box

Thanks in ahead for your help. I'm getting authorization code through exactly this website on the readme page: https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=security_token%3DKnhMJatFipTAnM0nHlZA

And POST for *access_token* through python. But receive *invalid_request* error. Same result as I try through postman.
Attached my code and the error msg, did I understand something wrong?

```
url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token'
payload = {'grant_type':'authorization_code','code':auth_code,'client_id':'ID','client_secret':'SECRET'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
json_r = r.json()
print json_r
```

Error message:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you encode the POST payload as a JSON-string when the [`requests.post`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post) function's `data` parameter expects an ordinary dictionary.
So just doing it like this should work:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Comment: It does work, thanks a lot! But sometimes I POST with JSON-string and it worked. It's kind of confusing. Thank you for this help!

Comment: @JoeyJiao you're welcome! You can pass a JSON-string as well if you use the ``json`` argument, i.e. ``requests.post(url, json=payload_as_json)`` - maybe that's why you were confused?

Comment: This also works: requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))  And: payload = {'name':'name', 'parent': {'id': '0'}} ... So it feels not clear to me. I really appreciate your suggestion!!